# Ubuntu running really slow

Tags: hardware, 17.04

first time posting here, so i have this laptop from 2009 which has this specs : intel centrino duo t2050 1.6 ghz
             3 gb of ram 
             nvidia go 7300 with 256 mb 
i recently installed ubuntu but its running pretty slow and i dont know why, opening a page feels laggy and watching videos on youtube is impossible, it is weird because on windows 10 the experience is fluid, im running ubuntu 17.04, any solutions or its just a matter of hardware. also i have tried to see if the gpu i was using was the correct one and it is.

Comment: Please open Settings > Software & Updates > Additional drivers. Wait a few moments until the window is populated. Select and apply the recommended proprietary driver (should be version 304.xx and nothing else). Reboot and test. (Windows already includes this driver).

Answer (score -1):

Try opening System Monitor and check 'Processes' and 'Resources' to see if you are, for example, running out of CPU, RAM, etc. or if a process is hogging resources. This will not resolve the issue, but refine the diagnosis of it.

If you can find out if it is your hardware causing the slowness (not a specific process/program using up all resources), then you may need to look into getting new hardware, or switching to a lighter weight version of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

If it is an issue of a single program or process taking up resources, then you could look to see if there are settings for that program to use less memory or look for a low usage alternative.

Just a tip about Markdown (how posts are formatted here): put a blank line whenever you want to have a new paragraph, and prepend lines of a list with `-`, `*`, or `+`. It will make it more readable.